# Reading the body of a request in hooks.server in sveltekit

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I want to read the body of a request in my hooks.server.ts
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

```
export const handle = (async ({ event, resolve }) => {
  console.log(event.request.body);
 
  const response = await resolve(event);
  return response;
}) satisfies Handle;
```

This gives me

```
ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }
```

If i read it

```
const reader = request.body.getReader();
let text;
let result;
while (!(result = await reader.read()).done) {
   text += result.value;
}
console.log(text);
console.log(request.body);
```

And then log the body, i get:

```
ReadableStream { locked: true, state: 'closed', supportsBYOB: false }
```

This leads to the actuall call I want to do to thrown an error

> TypeError: Body is unusable
> at specConsumeBody (/home/hp/git/booking/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js:492:11)
> at Request.json (/home/hp/git/booking/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js:359:14)

How can I read the body in hooks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [`clone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/clone) the `Request` and work with that to not modify the original.

Answer (score 18):

I got the error `TypeError: Body is unusable` when trying to debug a POST request with a JSON body because I did await the request twice.

```
console.log(await request.text()) // X only this is logged
console.log(await request.json()) // --> throws error
```

Instead, only await the request once!

```
console.log(await request.json()) // logs, no error
```